# Полчучаю ошибку cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js

Изменение продуктов. Когда пользователь который не имеет роли `admin` и пытается обновить данные об продукте, то он получает сообщение `"failed": "Unauthorized Access"`. С этим все нормально. Но как пользваотель с ролью `admin` пытается обновить, то не он получает сообщение `message: Product updated with id...`, и в консоль приходит сообщение `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. В чем я ошибся, где моя проблема?

```
//handles url http://localhost:6001/products/update
router.post("/update", (req, res, next) => {
  jwt.verify(req.headers.token, "secret", (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: err
      });
    } else {
      if (decoded.user_role === "admin") {
        //read product information from request
        let pid = req.body.prd_id;
        let product = new Product(req.body.prd_name, req.body.prd_price);

        db.query(product.getCheckByIdSQL(pid), (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({
              error: err
            });
          } else {
            if (Object.entries(data).length !== 0 && data.constructor !== Object) {
              db.query(product.updateProductByIdSQL(pid), (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                  return res.status(401).json({
                    error: err
                  });
                } else {
                  return res.status(200).json({
                    message: `Product updated with id = ${pid}.`,
                    productId: data.affectedRows
                  });
                }
              });
            } else {
              return res.status(200).json({
                failed: "No id"
              });
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
          failed: "Unauthorized Access"
        });
      }
    }
    next();
  });
});
```

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что вы пытаетесь отправить ответ клиенту дважды. Пересмотрите ваш код.

Comment: У вас срабатывает функция `next()` в любом случае, а судя по логике обработчика так не должно быть.

Comment: Без фенкции `next()` все работает хорошо, нет ошибок

Comment: Верните `next()` и везде, где у вас `res.status(..)`, замените на `return res.status(..)`, чтобы в случае ошибки не выполнять следующий обработчик

Comment: Сделал все как сказали, все рано ошибка `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` при изменение админом выходит. Изменил в вопросе код

Comment: Причину я вам назвал. НО у вас наблюдается запрос в БД, а он выполняется асинхронно - в `db.query` у вас коллбэк  выполняет `res.status()` уже после передачи выполнения след. обработчика `next()`.  Уберите этот код и проверьте или дождитесь его выполнения.

Comment: Убрал, ошибка остается по прежнему

Comment: Так подождите, у вас же больше обработчиков то нет??? Зачем вы используете функцию `next()` есть представление?)

Comment: Зачемс я использую функцию `next()` представления не имею. Есть добавление, изменение, удаление, вывод всех и вывод по `id`

Comment: Уберите её) и пройдитесь по [мануалу](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помошь)